# R - How to import S4 classes from another file?

Tags: r, r-s4

R beginner here. Let's say I have two R-files, one of them, "classFile.R" containing the S4 class "X". How can I import the code to use the X class in the other file?
I tried a simple `source("classFile.R")` but the classes are not known in my other file. What am I missing here?

Comment: `source` is the correct command.  When you say "the classes are not known in my other file", what do you mean?  Are you calling a function in `classFile.R` to create the S4 object in the other script?  Without knowing more about the contents of your scripts, it's hard to help.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific! The initialization of an object of class X fails, like ` foo <- new('X')`. The error message reads _Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “X” is not a defined class_

Comment: Do you have an S3 method for `new` in `classFile.R`?  Remember that objects in R are not like objects in most object-oriented languages.  There is no environment-based class definition.  It's just linked/overloaded function calls.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I got some stuff mixed up then. I used the [new](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/new.html) method for creating objects from my classes, which did work while the code was in a single file. Trying to initialize with `foo <- X()` (as seems to be a possible way to go with S4 classes?), again for the seperate files with a `source`, produces an error as well: _Error: could not find function "Layer"_

Comment: `X()` or `new()` in your examples are just function calls.  If your file called in `source` has functions with those names (overloading the basic functions in R such as `new` with class-specific variants) then they will work.  Objects in R are just special lists created by user- or package-defined functions such that they are in a known format, which is called its "S4 class".  The R environment itself has no awareness of objects.

Comment: I see! Well, the sourced file contains the Class definitions, made with [setClass](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setClass.html), which seems to create appropriate generator functions, so I assume those functions are somehow not passed on to/known in my other file?

Comment: What are the names of the "generator functions"?